# How can I exclude my tests package from source folder in an ant build file?

Tags: java, ant, build

I have the following declaration in my build.xml file, in my src folder I have my test package which I don't want to include into my process. How can I force scrdir to read everything from ${src.dir} except test package?

```
<target name="compile">  
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

```
<target name="compile">   
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
           excludes="mypackage/p1/testpackage/**"/>

</target>
```

Answer (score 3):

javac has `excludes` attribute where you can exclude the packages.